# solve differential equation with two possible answer

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

i tried to solve differential equation without independent variable 
$yy"+y'^2-1=0$ 
using substitution :
$y'=p$ and 
$y"=\frac{dp}{dx}=p \frac{dp}{dy}$

 after substitution:

$yp\frac{dp}{dy}+p^2-1=0$
 
 
then doing separation variable 
this is part that i got confused:
$\frac{p dp}{p^2-1}=- \frac{dy}{y}$ 
and 
$\frac{p dp}{1-p^2}= \frac{dy}{y}$ 
different place to put minus

i solve both but the gave different result, the first one i got right result, but from second one i got result that i cannot integrate it. 
first one: 
$yp\frac{dp}{dy}+p^2-1=0$
$\frac{2p}{p^2-1}dp+2 \frac{dy}{y}=0$
$\log (p^2-1)+2\log y= C_1$ 
$y \sqrt{p^2-1}=C$
$p^2=1+\frac{c}{y^2}$
here if i substitute back $y'=p $, i can integrate y  and got the result

second one:

$yp \frac{dp}{dy}=1-p^2$ 
$\frac{p}{1-p^2}dp=\frac{dy}{y}$
  then substitute $1-p^2=u $ 
$\sqrt{1-p^2}=y.C$ 
$p=\sqrt{1-y^2C}$
clearly if i substitute back $y'=p $ , i cannot integrate y to get y

so my question : are both of my approach wrong/right? and which one is right? and how to know which approach is right or wrong? thanks!!

Comment: sorry typo, already edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I'll give  a different appoach (count it as the third) just in case you interest.

Note that since $(yy')' = y'^2 + yy''$ the differential equation becomes $$(yy')' = 1$$
This yield the solution $$yy' = x + C$$ which can be rerwiten a $y dy = x dx + C dx$ and hence $$\frac{1}{2} y^2 = \frac{1}{2} x^2 + Cx + C_1 $$
for arbitrary constants $C$ and $C_1$.

Comment: thanks! i know this is right too! but if i finish my work i got  $y^2+C_1=(x+C_2)^2$ , is this mean that one problem could have many possible different answers?

Comment: @Vixf, your solution is exactly the same as Azlif's, just expand the bracket and rename the constants

Comment: @YuriyS okay, i got the result using the first approach, but if i use the second one $\frac{p}{1-p^2}dp=\frac{dy}{y}$ , i didn't get the same result and cannot integrate it

Comment: In the second one you forgot the negative sign when integrating with subs $1 - p^2 = u$. So it should be $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1 - p^2)}} = C.y$$ there

Comment: omg! many thanks!!! really silly mistake! thankyou so much!!!!!! :D